# How to put header on the top of everypage when generating pdf file with css/html placeholder?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, frontend

I am generating "Pdf file" with a header on the top of the first page and the same header on the top of the next page as HTML code.[The NAME on the bottom should go to next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll2dQ.png)

```
<!-- COVER LETTER -->
<div id="cover-letter" ng-show="cover.body && showingCoverLetter">
    <span class="name" ng-show="basics.name">{{basics.name}}</span>
<!-- RESUME -->
<div id="resume" span ng-show="showingResume">
    <span class="name" ng-show="basics.name">{{basics.name}}</span>
```

The Cover letter and Resume are two different pages and "name" should be on the top of these two pages. Here is CSS Code for printing:

```
#print-page{
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*Disabled these in print query*/
    mso-header-margin:.5in; mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;
    z-index: 0;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute !important;
    top:0px !important; left:0px !important;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    display: block !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

The problem is when downloading the pdf file,"name"of the RESUMEe goes to the bottom of COVER LETTER. 
And there goes my question: do you know any work-around for that problem? How can I  put "name" at the top of the page? Thanks in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: Which lib are you using to generate your PDF?

Comment: For this question you have to make plunker, live demo will helps you and others to get answer